# How to dynamically make checkbox readonly in jqGrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I need in general editable checkboxes in jqGrid, but some rows should have readonly checkboxes.

I set loadComplete to my jgGrid table parameter(it's a test code, so rowid and model are a mock):

```
tableParams.loadComplete = function(){
        var rowids = $("#acl_table").getDataIDs();
        var model = tableParams.colModel[0];
        $("#acl_table").setCell(rowids[0], model, "", "", {'disabled':'disabled'});
    };
```

I succeeded in overwriting a cell value like by

```
$("#acl_table").setCell(rowids[0], model, "False", "", {'disabled':'disabled'});
```

So this line itself should work, but the checkbox rests editable.

I know that checkbox's readonly are controlled by {formatoptions:{disabled:false}} in colModelSettings.
How can I change readonly settings or overwrite formatoptions in each cell/row?